# VB.NET trims received serial data

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to communicate with a micro-controller(Arduino) with VB.NET. I somehow able to establish connection between the two. However as I tested receiving and printing data from the micro-controller, It sometimes cuts the string off. Sometimes it shows a (?) symbol which I understand due to an unknown character. However I managed to set my character encoding along with the serial port object. Here is the snippet of my code (Declaration of serial port object from my class)

```
Public Function setSerialPortObjectParams(ByVal params As Collection)
    With Me.sp
        .Close()
        .PortName = params("port")
        .BaudRate = params("baud")
        .ReadTimeout = If(params.Contains("readTimeout"), params("readTimeout"), 500)
        .WriteTimeout = If(params.Contains("writeTimeout"), params("writeTimeout"), 500)
        .ReadTimeout = If(params.Contains("readTimeout"), params("readTimeout"), 500)
        .DataBits = If(params.Contains("bits"), params("bits"), 8)
        .Parity = If(params.Contains("parity"), params("parity"), Parity.None)
        .StopBits = If(params.Contains("stopBits"), params("stopBits"), StopBits.One)
        .Handshake = If(params.Contains("handShake"), params("handShake"), Handshake.None)
        .Encoding = If(params.Contains("encoding"), params("encoding"), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    End With

    Return Me
End Function
```

Here is the screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

as you can see from the image, when I clicked "LED ON" button, it will suppose to 
send "on" command to the micro-controller and from there, it will serial print the received string which is "on" back to the application. However, there is a trimming of string happening somewhere out there that I do not know what caused it?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You posted the wrong code, there's something wrong with the way you read the response.  Probably because you are using ReadExisting() instead of ReadLine().

Comment: Are you saying the microprocessor echos the command?

Comment: I actually did ReadLine() on my code. 
@dbasnett: sorry - edited now its micro-controller.

Comment: Is the device attached echoing the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seriously consider using firmata to simplify communicating with an arduino from vb.net.  Go [here](http://www.acraigie.com/programming/firmatavb/default.html) to get a .net compatible wrapper for it. There is example code in the downloads section on that site as well, so you won't have to start from scratch.

Comment: thanks for this helpful reference man. Do you have some example / application using this? I understand the vb part but for the arduino, do you have some examples on this? thanks.

Comment: @adlee I'm kind of surfing into new territory here myself, so none of my own creation that I can share as of yet. However, I think the main wiki for firmata can get you started on the arduino side: [link](http://firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: okay.. thanks for this. will take a further look on this reference.. again.. much thanks!..

Comment: @AldeeMativo I forgot to add that firmata is included in the standard arduino IDE (v1.0.3+).  So there should be some helpful examples to look through there as well.

Comment: yes.. I see it from the IDE and I just ignored it since I do not know before what and how it works.. great thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code maybe can be helpful i know is 2 or 3 yeas later but for new people can be helpfull.....

To check if the port is available. Pls be sure that the arduino is connected to that port....

```
Imports Firmata.FirmataVB
Imports Firmata.DigitalPinControl

Public Class Form1
    Dim intensity, timerpwrpin, pin, change As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim pantallas As String
        'It validate if they are 3 monitors connected to the system if less or more than 3 the program closes automaticaly.
        pantallas = Screen.AllScreens.Count.ToString()

        If pantallas = 3 Then
            'screen form 1 = center of the screen
            Show()
            Location = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Location + New Point(0, 0)
        End If



        FirmataVB1.COMPortName = "COM6"  '' Specify the COM port of our board
        FirmataVB1.Baud = "57600"  '' Specify the port speed
        FirmataVB1.Connect() '' is connected to the board
        intensity = 0 ' pwr variation variable from 0 to 255 where 0 = off and 255 max power.
        change = 0 ' change 1 increase pwr or 0 decrease
        timerpwrpin = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        FirmataVB1.Disconnect() '' will close the ports when closing the program
    End Sub
    Sub pinarduino(sensornumber, pulseorpwr, onoff, valpwr)
        FirmataVB1.PinMode(sensornumber, pulseorpwr) 'where 3 - is the transition mode PWM and 1 just pulse
        If pulseorpwr = 1 Then
            FirmataVB1.DigitalWrite(sensornumber, onoff) ' where valuenumber  in the arduino board  1  output on 0 the output off
        End If
        If pulseorpwr = 3 Then
            FirmataVB1.AnalogWrite(sensornumber, valpwr) ' where valuenumber  in the arduino board  1  output on 0 the output off
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub clean()
        For i = 2 To 13
            pinarduino(i, 0, 0, 0)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btndigitalpulse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndigitalpulse.Click
        pinarduino(pin, 1, 1, 0) '/pinarduino(sensornumber, pulseorpwr, onoff, valpwr)
        '/pinarduino(pinnumber, modepulse, onoff, na in this case)
        TrackBar1.Value = 255
        chklst.SetItemCheckState(pin - 2, CheckState.Checked)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnpwrtest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnpwrtest.Click
        pinarduino(pin, 3, 1, 0)

        Select Case pin
            Case 1
                'does not exist
            Case 2
                'does not exist
            Case 3
                chb3.Checked = True
                Timer1.Start()
            Case 4
                'does not exist
            Case 5
                Timer1.Start()
                chb5.Checked = True
            Case 6
                Timer1.Start()
                chb6.Checked = True
            Case 7
                'does not exist
            Case 8
                'does not exist
            Case 9
                Timer1.Start()
                chb9.Checked = True
            Case 10
                Timer1.Start()
                chb10.Checked = True
            Case 11
                Timer1.Start()
                chb11.Checked = True
            Case 12
                'does not exist
            Case 13
                'does not exist
        End Select
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnstoptest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnstoptest.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
        pinarduino(pin, 1, 0, 0)
        TrackBar1.Value = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Click
        pinarduino(pin, 3, 1, TrackBar1.Value)
    End Sub





    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'FirmataVB1.AnalogWrite(timerpwrpin, i) ' where intensity - is a value from 0 to 255

        If change = 0 Then
            intensity = intensity + 1
            If intensity = 255 Then change = 1
        End If

        If change = 1 Then
            intensity = intensity - 1
            If intensity = 0 Then change = 0
        End If

        FirmataVB1.AnalogWrite(pin, intensity) ' where intensity - is a value from 0 to 255
        TrackBar1.Value = intensity

    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
        pin = 2
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
        pin = 3
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
        pin = 4
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.CheckedChanged
        pin = 5
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton6_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton6.CheckedChanged
        pin = 6
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton7_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton7.CheckedChanged
        pin = 7
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton8_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton8.CheckedChanged
        pin = 8
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton9_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton9.CheckedChanged
        pin = 9
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton10_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton10.CheckedChanged
        pin = 10
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton11_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton11.CheckedChanged
        pin = 11
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton12_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton12.CheckedChanged
        pin = 12
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton13_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton13.CheckedChanged
        pin = 13
        btnpwrtest.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnstopall_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnstopall.Click
        clean()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnexit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the form....

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.FirmataVB1 = New Firmata.FirmataVB(Me.components)
        Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        Me.btnplayvideo = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.Btnstopall = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.RadioButton13 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.chklst = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox()
        Me.RadioButton12 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton11 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton10 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton9 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton8 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton7 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton6 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton5 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton4 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton3 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.RadioButton2 = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.btnstoptest = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.TrackBar1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar()
        Me.btnpwrtest = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.btndigitalpulse = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.btnstopvideo = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.btnexit = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.chb3 = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
        Me.chb5 = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
        Me.chb6 = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
        Me.chb11 = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
        Me.chb10 = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
        Me.chb9 = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
        Me.Panel1.SuspendLayout()
        CType(Me.TrackBar1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'FirmataVB1
        '
        Me.FirmataVB1.Baud = 115200
        Me.FirmataVB1.BoardType = Firmata.FirmataVB.Board.DUEMILANOVE
        Me.FirmataVB1.COMPortName = "COM6"
        Me.FirmataVB1.WithAnalogReceiveEvents = True
        Me.FirmataVB1.WithDigitalReceiveEvents = True
        Me.FirmataVB1.WithVersionReceieveEvents = True
        '
        'Timer1
        '
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 1
        '
        'btnplayvideo
        '
        Me.btnplayvideo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(552, 371)
        Me.btnplayvideo.Name = "btnplayvideo"
        Me.btnplayvideo.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 39)
        Me.btnplayvideo.TabIndex = 5
        Me.btnplayvideo.Text = "Play Video"
        Me.btnplayvideo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Panel1
        '
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.chb11)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.chb10)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.chb9)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.chb6)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.chb5)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.chb3)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Btnstopall)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton13)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.chklst)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton12)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton11)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton10)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton9)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton8)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton7)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton6)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton5)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton4)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton3)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton2)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.btnstoptest)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.TrackBar1)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.btnpwrtest)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.btndigitalpulse)
        Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
        Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(822, 291)
        Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 33
        '
        'Btnstopall
        '
        Me.Btnstopall.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(683, 68)
        Me.Btnstopall.Name = "Btnstopall"
        Me.Btnstopall.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 39)
        Me.Btnstopall.TabIndex = 52
        Me.Btnstopall.Text = "Stop All"
        Me.Btnstopall.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton13
        '
        Me.RadioButton13.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton13.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(23, 256)
        Me.RadioButton13.Name = "RadioButton13"
        Me.RadioButton13.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(37, 17)
        Me.RadioButton13.TabIndex = 51
        Me.RadioButton13.TabStop = True
        Me.RadioButton13.Text = "13"
        Me.RadioButton13.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Label2
        '
        Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(121, 57)
        Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
        Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(79, 13)
        Me.Label2.TabIndex = 50
        Me.Label2.Text = "CHECKED PIN"
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(19, 57)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 13)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 49
        Me.Label1.Text = "PIN NUMBER"
        '
        'chklst
        '
        Me.chklst.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
        Me.chklst.Enabled = False
        Me.chklst.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.chklst.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"})
        Me.chklst.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(124, 90)
        Me.chklst.Name = "chklst"
        Me.chklst.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 184)
        Me.chklst.TabIndex = 48
        '
        'RadioButton12
        '
        Me.RadioButton12.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton12.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 241)
        Me.RadioButton12.Name = "RadioButton12"
        Me.RadioButton12.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(37, 17)
        Me.RadioButton12.TabIndex = 47
        Me.RadioButton12.Text = "12"
        Me.RadioButton12.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton11
        '
        Me.RadioButton11.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton11.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 226)
        Me.RadioButton11.Name = "RadioButton11"
        Me.RadioButton11.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(37, 17)
        Me.RadioButton11.TabIndex = 46
        Me.RadioButton11.Text = "11"
        Me.RadioButton11.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton10
        '
        Me.RadioButton10.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton10.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 211)
        Me.RadioButton10.Name = "RadioButton10"
        Me.RadioButton10.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(37, 17)
        Me.RadioButton10.TabIndex = 45
        Me.RadioButton10.Text = "10"
        Me.RadioButton10.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton9
        '
        Me.RadioButton9.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton9.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 196)
        Me.RadioButton9.Name = "RadioButton9"
        Me.RadioButton9.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton9.TabIndex = 44
        Me.RadioButton9.Text = "9"
        Me.RadioButton9.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton8
        '
        Me.RadioButton8.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 181)
        Me.RadioButton8.Name = "RadioButton8"
        Me.RadioButton8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton8.TabIndex = 43
        Me.RadioButton8.Text = "8"
        Me.RadioButton8.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton7
        '
        Me.RadioButton7.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 166)
        Me.RadioButton7.Name = "RadioButton7"
        Me.RadioButton7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton7.TabIndex = 42
        Me.RadioButton7.Text = "7"
        Me.RadioButton7.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton6
        '
        Me.RadioButton6.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton6.Checked = True
        Me.RadioButton6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 150)
        Me.RadioButton6.Name = "RadioButton6"
        Me.RadioButton6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton6.TabIndex = 41
        Me.RadioButton6.TabStop = True
        Me.RadioButton6.Text = "6"
        Me.RadioButton6.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton5
        '
        Me.RadioButton5.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 135)
        Me.RadioButton5.Name = "RadioButton5"
        Me.RadioButton5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton5.TabIndex = 40
        Me.RadioButton5.Text = "5"
        Me.RadioButton5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton4
        '
        Me.RadioButton4.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 120)
        Me.RadioButton4.Name = "RadioButton4"
        Me.RadioButton4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton4.TabIndex = 39
        Me.RadioButton4.Text = "4"
        Me.RadioButton4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton3
        '
        Me.RadioButton3.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 105)
        Me.RadioButton3.Name = "RadioButton3"
        Me.RadioButton3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton3.TabIndex = 38
        Me.RadioButton3.Text = "3"
        Me.RadioButton3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'RadioButton2
        '
        Me.RadioButton2.AutoSize = True
        Me.RadioButton2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 90)
        Me.RadioButton2.Name = "RadioButton2"
        Me.RadioButton2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
        Me.RadioButton2.TabIndex = 37
        Me.RadioButton2.Text = "2"
        Me.RadioButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'btnstoptest
        '
        Me.btnstoptest.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(727, 9)
        Me.btnstoptest.Name = "btnstoptest"
        Me.btnstoptest.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 39)
        Me.btnstoptest.TabIndex = 36
        Me.btnstoptest.Text = "Stop Pin"
        Me.btnstoptest.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'TrackBar1
        '
        Me.TrackBar1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(7, 9)
        Me.TrackBar1.Maximum = 255
        Me.TrackBar1.Name = "TrackBar1"
        Me.TrackBar1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(504, 45)
        Me.TrackBar1.TabIndex = 35
        Me.TrackBar1.TickFrequency = 5
        '
        'btnpwrtest
        '
        Me.btnpwrtest.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(633, 9)
        Me.btnpwrtest.Name = "btnpwrtest"
        Me.btnpwrtest.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 39)
        Me.btnpwrtest.TabIndex = 34
        Me.btnpwrtest.Text = "PWR TEST"
        Me.btnpwrtest.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'btndigitalpulse
        '
        Me.btndigitalpulse.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(540, 9)
        Me.btndigitalpulse.Name = "btndigitalpulse"
        Me.btndigitalpulse.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 39)
        Me.btndigitalpulse.TabIndex = 33
        Me.btndigitalpulse.Text = "I/O Pulse"
        Me.btndigitalpulse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'btnstopvideo
        '
        Me.btnstopvideo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(645, 371)
        Me.btnstopvideo.Name = "btnstopvideo"
        Me.btnstopvideo.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 39)
        Me.btnstopvideo.TabIndex = 34
        Me.btnstopvideo.Text = "Stop Video"
        Me.btnstopvideo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'btnexit
        '
        Me.btnexit.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(739, 371)
        Me.btnexit.Name = "btnexit"
        Me.btnexit.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 39)
        Me.btnexit.TabIndex = 35
        Me.btnexit.Text = "Exit"
        Me.btnexit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Label3
        '
        Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(222, 57)
        Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
        Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(87, 13)
        Me.Label3.TabIndex = 53
        Me.Label3.Text = "CHECKED PWR"
        '
        'chb3
        '
        Me.chb3.AutoSize = True
        Me.chb3.Enabled = False
        Me.chb3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(225, 105)
        Me.chb3.Name = "chb3"
        Me.chb3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(32, 17)
        Me.chb3.TabIndex = 54
        Me.chb3.Text = "3"
        Me.chb3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'chb5
        '
        Me.chb5.AutoSize = True
        Me.chb5.Enabled = False
        Me.chb5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(225, 135)
        Me.chb5.Name = "chb5"
        Me.chb5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(32, 17)
        Me.chb5.TabIndex = 55
        Me.chb5.Text = "5"
        Me.chb5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'chb6
        '
        Me.chb6.AutoSize = True
        Me.chb6.Enabled = False
        Me.chb6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(225, 150)
        Me.chb6.Name = "chb6"
        Me.chb6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(32, 17)
        Me.chb6.TabIndex = 56
        Me.chb6.Text = "6"
        Me.chb6.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'chb11
        '
        Me.chb11.AutoSize = True
        Me.chb11.Enabled = False
        Me.chb11.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(226, 228)
        Me.chb11.Name = "chb11"
        Me.chb11.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(38, 17)
        Me.chb11.TabIndex = 59
        Me.chb11.Text = "11"
        Me.chb11.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'chb10
        '
        Me.chb10.AutoSize = True
        Me.chb10.Enabled = False
        Me.chb10.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(226, 213)
        Me.chb10.Name = "chb10"
        Me.chb10.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(38, 17)
        Me.chb10.TabIndex = 58
        Me.chb10.Text = "10"
        Me.chb10.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'chb9
        '
        Me.chb9.AutoSize = True
        Me.chb9.Enabled = False
        Me.chb9.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(225, 196)
        Me.chb9.Name = "chb9"
        Me.chb9.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(32, 17)
        Me.chb9.TabIndex = 57
        Me.chb9.Text = "9"
        Me.chb9.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1904, 1042)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnexit)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnstopvideo)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Panel1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnplayvideo)
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.MinimizeBox = False
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.ShowIcon = False
        Me.Text = "Emir"
        Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.Panel1.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.Panel1.PerformLayout()
        CType(Me.TrackBar1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents FirmataVB1 As Firmata.FirmataVB
    Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Friend WithEvents btnplayvideo As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents Panel1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    Friend WithEvents Btnstopall As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton13 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents chklst As System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton12 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton11 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton10 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton9 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton8 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton7 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton6 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton5 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton4 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton3 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents RadioButton2 As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents btnstoptest As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents TrackBar1 As System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar
    Friend WithEvents btnpwrtest As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents btndigitalpulse As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents btnstopvideo As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents btnexit As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents chb11 As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents chb10 As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents chb9 As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents chb6 As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents chb5 As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents chb3 As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label

End Class
```